# Fermions from lattice model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, lattice-model

In [TASI Lectures on Emergence of Supersymmetry, Gauge Theory and String in Condensed Matter Systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5127) from lattice Hamiltonian, which describe **fermions on honeycomb lattice**:

$$
H_f = -t_f \sum_{\langle ij \rangle} (f_i^\dagger f_j +h.c.)
$$

From this, author obtain in **continum limit**:

$$
\mathcal{L} = i \sum_{n=1}^{2} \bar{\psi}_n (\gamma_0 \partial_\tau+ c_f\sum_{i=1}^{2} \gamma_i \partial_i )\psi_n
$$

How to do continum limit in such model?

What is origin of coefficient $c_f$?

Comment: Isn't that basically the Dirac lagrangian? And the for the bosonic part, it's basically the Klein-Gordon lagrangian. $c_f$ is whatever constants appear before the kinetic part of the equation, like $\hbar c$ for Dirac and $\hbar^2/2m$ for Schrödinger.

Comment: @SuperCiocia I think, that one need some peculiar initial data to obtain Lorentz invariant theory

Answer (score 4):

The  honeycomb lattice model is the tight-binding version of [graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#History). To get the "continuum" limit one observes that each unit cell contains two lattice sites, so you need a two-component Bloch vector. You then follow [Wallace](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.71.622) solve the band theory and find that the valance and conduction bands touch at two points (${\bf k}_i$ $i=1,2$)  in the Brillouin zone and in the vicinity of each of these points the 2-by-2 matrix can be approximated by a  two component Weyl hamiltonian
$$
H= (-1)^i v_f {\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot ({\bf k}-{\bf k}_i)
$$
where $ v_f\equiv c_f\propto t_f$.  Hence your second Weyl Lagrangian expression.  It's good exercise to work this out!